# JSP Serve Static Files Located on a Separate Server

Tags: jsp

This may be a very rudimentary question, in which the answer is "It can not be done", which I am OK with.

So we have a couple of instances where users have set up folders on their local Linux based web servers that hold static text files.

We developed a file browser object, which uses the page context and a set path, that explores the base directory and then generates links to these files and displays them on the resulting web page. This process works fine for these local, isolated instances.

Now we have a group that wants to do the same thing. However, the difference is their web server is a shared server and they want to use this file browser object to pull the static files off of their local server.

Basically:

- Shared server hosts the web page
- Shared server searches file system of local server
- Local server hosts static files

Is this even possible? Would there have to be a share setup between the local server and the shared web server?

This is all new to me, so I do apologize.

Comment: Yes, you can, you can either use virtual directory or symlinks.

Comment: @Hackerman, thank you. You gave me some ideas with which to discuss with the shared server's owner.

If you add that as an answer, I would be happy the accept it.

Comment: Glad to help Paul!